# disable the use of ubuntu at night with an password

Tags: system-settings, parental-controls

Is it possible to have a similar function as the IOS screen time limitation? For example, for certain time during the day, one could not use the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this project [Timekpr-nExT](https://launchpad.net/timekpr-next) that does precisely that (similar to parental controls). You could use it for your own user if you want to limit yourself of screen time.